# Creating a array of promises with .map will call the promise?

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-promise

I have the following

```
const ingredientsPromises = ingredients.map(ingredient =>
    // Is this .map calling the api?
    axios.post('/api/ingredient', ingredient)
)
await Promise.all(ingredientsPromises)
    .then(consoleThen)
    .catch(consoleCatch)
```

I'm making multiple calls to an api, but what I'm not sure is that when the promise will run, will it run inside `.map` or only in `Promise.all`?

Comment: The Promise callbacks happen when the requests complete; they're not "in" anything.

Comment: @Pointy but where is the resquest send? In the `.map` or `Promise.all`? How does it work?

Comment: That's what `axios.post()` does. That *initiates* an HTTP request and returns a Promise.

Comment: So... it's sending the request "inside"  `.map`?

Comment: Yes, and the resulting array (`ingredientsPromises`) will contain all those Promise objects.

Comment: @Pointy so this means that in my case, `Promise.all` is useless?

Comment: No, quite the contrary. Have you tried your code? It's not clear what's going on in this question; where did the code come from?

Comment: You don't need the `await` because you're explicitly adding your own `.then()` callback.

Comment: @Pointy yes, I tried the code and I made it by myself. It works and do what I want, but I'm not sure how the promises are working

Comment: The Promise objects are created by the axios library code, and `.post()` returns each one.  `Promise.all()` will wait for all of the Promise objects in the array to be fulfilled, and then your `.then()` callback is invoked.

Comment: @Vencovsky Why do you think `Promise.all` is useless? It's absolutely necessary for the `consoleThen` to work, you cannot just omit it

Answer (score 1):

Promise will run individually. It is up to you when do you want to do something with it.

If you want to do something after each individual request is completed then you can just use

```
const ingredientsPromises = ingredients.map(ingredient =>
    // Is this .map calling the api?
    axios.post('/api/ingredient', ingredient)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
   .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

)
```

Otherwise you can use the promise returned by 'all' function like this. If you want to do something after all promises are resolved.

```
const ingredientsPromises = ingredients.map(ingredient =>
    // Is this .map calling the api?
    axios.post('/api/ingredient', ingredient)
)
await Promise.all(ingredientsPromises)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
   .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Also await won't do anything here so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ingredientsPromises = ingredients.map(ingredient =>
    // Is this .map calling the api?
    axios.post('/api/ingredient', ingredient)
)
```

Yes, this is initiating your API request(s).

> A promise will always return a promise.

Lets see what's happening here,

First of all, `ingredientsPromises` is initialized with array of promises (each promise representing your API request in **pending** state).

**At this point of time, all of your requests had been initiated.**

from the docs,

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

So, with `Promise.all(ingredientsPromises)` you are resolving all these pending promises, which **returns another promise (which means you have received the API response)** either in *fulfilled* state (in case no error occurs), or in *rejected* state (in case one or more requests fail)

Answer (score -4):

I use bluebird [map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) function for this

```
  await bluebird.map(ingredients, (i) => axios.post('/api/ingredient', i))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.